# How to fix "Error: Only <glib.h> can be included directly."

Tags: c, glib

Under Linux Mint, trying make gnome-vfs-2.0.4, but I got the error messages:

```
/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:31:2: error: #error "Only glib.h can be included directly."

glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:35:2: error: #error "Only glib.h can be included directly."

glib-2.0/glib/gversionmacros.h:31:2: error: #error "Only glib.h can be included directly."

glib-2.0/glib/glist.h:31:2: error: #error "Only  glib.h can be included directly."

glib-2.0/glib/gmem.h:31:2: error: #error "Only glib.h can be included directly."

glib-2.0/glib/gnode.h:31:2: error: #error "Only glib.h can be included directly."
```

I google it, and it is said I should change `#include <glib/xxx.h>`  to `#include <glib.h>`, but more errors occur after I do so.

How to fix it?

Comment: When you want to type something `<in angled brackets>`, escape it with apostrophes (the ones on your tilde key).

Comment: Thanks,Maciej Stachowski.

Comment: Also, what kind of errors do you get once you replace `<glib/xxx.h>` with `<glib.h>`?

Answer (score 2):

why are you trying to compile a long since deprecated library like gnome-vfs? also, why are you trying to compile gnome-vfs 2.0.4, which is 11 years old, using a version of GLib that is clearly more recent?

GLib started only allowing including the top-level "glib.h" header years ago; I'm not entirely sure gnome-vfs was ever updated to do so, because it's been deprecated for 5 years, now.

in general, you want to try building a newer version of gnome-vfs — the latest is 2.24.4, released 3 years ago. if that does build, you'll have to modify gnome-vfs to always only include the top-level glib header. this means editing all source files that include things like "glist.h", "gmem.h", "gnode.h", etc. and replace them with:

```
#include <glib.h>
```

and then rebuild.

my actual suggestion, though, is to not use a deprecated library with no maintenance, and with known issues. if you have access to a recent version of GLib, you can use GIO — the library shipped with GLib that replaced gnome-vfs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ebassi. Actually I am trying to configure FlashExtractor-2.3.2, which needs gnome-vfs. Making gnome-vfs -2.24.4, I got these errors: 

gnome-vfs-async-job-map.c:30:1: error： unknown type name‘GStaticRecMutex’

gnome-vfs-async-job-map.c:30:45: error： ‘G_STATIC_REC_MUTEX_INIT’undefined

Comment: you honestly cannot pretend to use software that has long since been unmaintained with latest releases of its dependencies. in this case, GStaticRecMutex has been deprecated for almost two years. gnome-vfs seems to disable deprecated API, so you'll need to remove any #define for G_DISABLE_DEPRECATED in the build or in the source code. or ask whosoever maintains FlashExtractor to port their code to use something that hasn't been deprecated for more than 5 years. alternatively, try to compile all the dependencies using older versions.

Comment: Honestly, there is a lot of software still using GTK2 - you may not happen to like it, but its difficult to port every single bit of software out there to gtk3, especially when you factor in all the bindings on top of gtk and the different versions of software... The problem is specifically that software from this era was not very good at specifiying the dependencies up-front.

Comment: @smaudet This has nothing to do with GTK: gnome-vfs has been deprecated way before GTK 3.0 was released, because its functionality was moved into GLib itself (under the GIO name). Gnome-VFS is unmaintained and it artificially restricts its build to disable deprecated symbols, which is a recipe for disaster, given that nobody will keep it up to date any more.